# Can any one help in following problem in Netbeans running java code 

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

This happens when I try to run my project in netbeans 6.9.1 and there is no error in any java files.

debug:

```
Have no file for C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: qkd/QKDApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: qkd.QKDApp
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: qkd.QKDApp.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Did you import the jar file that contains `qkd.QKDApp`?

Comment: jdk.boot.jar or wat .. no i didnt import this one

Comment: qkd is package name and i deleted the qkdapp file as it was buld and was no use to me

Comment: pls any one can suggest somthing

Comment: Not jdk.boot.jar. This is what java is complaining about `Could not find the main class: qkd.QKDApp.  Program will exit.`

Comment: If you deleted the qkdapp, then dereference it from your project.

Comment: ya but wat should i dereference and make changes because i m new to netbeans .. so can u suggest some soln pls ..

Comment: i hav deference every thing thnx for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project properties (right click on your project and select properties). Select under categories Run. Check the setting for your main class. I expect it is still set to qkd.QKDApp enter the class name of your new main class.